# Django ERR_BLOCKED_BY_XSS_AUDITOR

Tags: django

I have a FormView which allows our users to edit the content of an HTML page.

```
class PrelanderUpdate(LoginRequiredMixin, SuccessMessageMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Prelander
    form_class = PrelanderForm

    template_name = 'generic/form.html'
    success_message = 'Prelander updated successfully.'

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('mediabuying:prelander:list')
```

This is my form:

```
class PrelanderForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Prelander
        fields = [
            'is_active', 'vertical', 'angle',
            'description', 'static_prefix', 'content'
        ]
        help_texts = {
            'description': '<i>Keep this short:</i> This will be shown in the dropdown',     # noqa
            'content': 'HTML code only.',
            'static_prefix': 'folder name in s3',
        }

    vertical = forms.ChoiceField(choices=Choices.Verticals)

    def clean_content(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data['content']
        if '<meta name="referrer" content="always">' not in data:
            raise forms.ValidationError(
                'Missing <meta name="referrer" content="always">'
            )
        return data
```

When I edit the `content` of a prelander, if the prelander does not have `<meta name="referrer" content="always">` and the validation error is thrown, I am seeing this error:

[image]

Why is this happening? Why does this only happen when the exception is thrown?

(The content of a prelander is an html page)

Comment: how are you displaying the content of your form? When a ValidationError is occurring, presumably you're re-rendering your page with the `content` field. If this contains raw HTML with scripts, chrome will block it as that's how attackers perform XSS attacks. You could add the `X-XSS-Protection: 0` header to prevent checking of XSS although I'm not sure that works in latest browsers.

Comment: I am displaying it in a textarea.